# How to properly downmix 5.1 sound to stereo

Tags: windows-10, stereo, 5.1

I usually watching Blu-Rays with PowerDVD 16. For some time now, instead of a monitor and a 5.1 sound system I used before, I use a television via HDMI now. The television only has Stereo.

When I had the 5.1 sound system I usually turned the center a lot louder than the rest to properly hear voices.

Now, with the television, I cannot mix the channels at all. PowerDVD or Windows (don't now which) automatically downmix the channels to stereo somehow. But the voices are too quiet most of the time.

How can I change that. My first instinct was to have a virtual sound device (with 6 channels) where I can customize the mix myself and the result is then send to the real sound device. I haven't found anything on this.

Via Google I found somethings about "AC3Filter" and "ffmpeg" and that those applications are able to properly downmix the sound. But I haven't found anything on how this works, only that it should work.

Can anyone explain to me, how this works?

PS: I know that PowerDVD is propably not able to use 3rd party filters and stuff. So I think VLC or similar players are also possible.

Comment: You are not clear at all as to what is connected to what and how.  Apparently a TV is involved and maybe a PC?  Is there a HDMI connection between the two?  What speakers are involved?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I try to explain the setting better. Before I had a 5,1 sound system. It has 3 jacks (green, orange and black). In Windows I have a driver from Realtek. If the 5.1 system is connected I can change the volume of all the 6 channels indivually. That means, if I watch a blu ray I can manipulate the voice relative to the other sound effects by changing the center volume. - Now I have a television (Panasonic VIERA) connected via HDMI. The sound plays via HDMI and Realtek cannot change volumes. Also 5.1 is automatically mixed into stereo signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mpv for that.

Just add a line like this to mpv.conf:

`af=lavfi=[lowpass=c=LFE:f=120,pan=stereo|FL=2FL+.21FC+.3FLC+.3SL+.3BL+.21BC+.21LFE|FR=.3FR+.21FC+.3FRC+.3SR+.3BR+.21BC+.21LFE]`

Here with 3dB boost to the front center channel:

`af=lavfi=[lowpass=c=LFE:f=120,pan=stereo|FL=2FL+.3FC+.3FLC+.3SL+.3BL+.21BC+.21LFE|FR=.3FR+.3FC+.3FRC+.3SR+.3BR+.21BC+.21LFE]`

Or with 6dB boost to the front center channel:

`af=lavfi=[lowpass=c=LFE:f=120,pan=stereo|FL=2FL+.42FC+.3FLC+.3SL+.3BL+.21BC+.21LFE|FR=.3FR+.42FC+.3FRC+.3SR+.3BR+.21BC+.21LFE]`

It has one problem though: It's also active for stereo sources, and reduces their loudness by about 10 dB, which is quite a lot.